# Ajax отправка данных с формы https на http

Tags: ajax

Добрый день, есть такая вот оптравка:

```
var form_data = $(this).serialize(); 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://*****/****.php",
            dataType: "text/html",
            data: form_data,
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
            success: function() {
               alert("Ваше сообщение отпрвлено!");
            }
        });
```

Вопрос состоит в том, как без пользовательского вмешательства (разрешение на перессылку и тд), можно реализовать такой финт ушами? Благодарю за понимание и помощь.